# DirectX9 Matrix Transforms not applying

Tags: c++, graphics, matrix, transform, directx-9

I have an Object class that keeps track of the objects scale, translation and everything else, and I want it to set those transform matrices when it draws(obviously), but for some reason, despite that I set the transform and everything, it does not work.

---------- IN OBJECT------------------

```
  vertices = new Vertex[vertexCount];
  scaleX = 100.0f;
  scaleY = 100.0f;
  scaleZ = 100.0f;
  vertices[0] = { 100.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 1, 0, };
  vertices[1] = { 100.0f, 100.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 1, 1, };
  vertices[2] = { 0.0f, 100.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 0, 1, };
  vertices[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, };

  v_buffer = NULL;
  i_buffer = NULL;

  texture = 0;

  d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(vertexCount * sizeof(Vertex),
    0,
    CUSTOMFVF,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    &v_buffer,
    NULL);

  short indices[] =
  {
    0, 1, 2,    // side 1
    2, 3, 0,
  };


  // create an index buffer interface called i_buffer
  d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(6 * sizeof(short),
    0,
    D3DFMT_INDEX16,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    &i_buffer,
    NULL);

  // lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
  i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
  memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
  i_buffer->Unlock();

  // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
  v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
  memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(Vertex)* vertexCount);
  v_buffer->Unlock();
```

-----------DRAW FUNCTION --------------

      `D3DXVECTOR3 pos = { obj.GetX(), obj.GetY(), obj.GetZ() };`

```
  d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);
  // select the vertex buffer to display
  d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, obj.GetVBuffer(), 0, sizeof(Vertex));
  d3ddev->SetIndices(obj.GetIBuffer());

  D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&obj.rotationTransform, obj.GetRotationX(), obj.GetRotationY(), obj.GetRotationZ());
  D3DXMatrixTranslation(&obj.translationTransform, obj.GetX(), obj.GetY(), obj.GetZ());
  D3DXMatrixScaling(&obj.scalingTransform, obj.GetScaleX(), obj.GetScaleY(), obj.GetScaleZ());
  D3DXMatrixMultiply(&obj.worldTransform, &obj.scalingTransform, &obj.translationTransform);
  D3DXMatrixMultiply(&obj.worldTransform, &obj.rotationTransform, &obj.worldTransform);
  //obj.worldTransform = obj.rotationTransform * obj.scalingTransform * obj.translationTransform;
  d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &obj.worldTransform);

  D3DXMatrixLookAtRH(&obj.viewTransform, &D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 10), &D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 0), &D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 0));
  d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &obj.viewTransform);

  D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovRH(&obj.projectionTransform, D3DXToRadian(90), (float)SCREEN_WIDTH / (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1.0f, 10.0f);
  d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &obj.projectionTransform);

  // copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
  d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you are doing wrong with the multiplication of the matrices. Matrix multiplication is not commutative, that is A*B != B*A. Change the order you multiply them in from rotation*scale*translate to scale*rotation*translate.

Hope that helps.